# WPF IValueConverter for DataGrid.Cell Tooltip Visibility getting null Value in Convert

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, ivalueconverter

XAML for Converter

```
   <ToolTip x:Key="toolTipGridCell" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget,
         RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"

         Visibility="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, 
         RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, 
         Converter={StaticResource ContentFitsVisibilityConverter}}">

        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Content.Text}"/>

    </ToolTip>
 ....
<DataGrid ....>
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource toolTipGridCell}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

I need to either hide or show the tooltip on the cell bases on whether the content of that cell is fully visible given the cell's width.

When I remove the Visibility part of the ToolTip, I get the tool tip with cell contents - so the targeting seems to be correct.

But with the visibility defined as above, when the Convert function gets hit as I mouse over the cell, the first parameter (object value) is null, instead of being the DataGrid.Cell over which the tooltip is showing up.

Comment: Why both the datacontext and the visibility are bound to PLacementTarget. I suspect the excception is because you are not binding to proper values

Comment: Are you aware of RelativeSource.Self ?? beccause i dont think it is relevant here that too in datacontext.

Comment: @Sivasubramanian

Thank you, that was the problem. I thought I had to do the binding same way as I bound the tooltip itself.

Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ContentFitsVisibilityConverter}}" was all that was needed

Comment: @Sivasubramanian or user1250290, do you want to post the answer?

Comment: @McGarnagle Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Sample Code you have provided, both the datacontext and the visibility of the Tooltip control are bound to the same property "PlacementTarget". This caused the NullReferenceException. To Resolve this issue, bind datacontext and the visibility to the appropriate property in your viewmodel.